# How to add or multiply data fields values in QRDBtext report?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, quickreports

Hi I am using Delphi 7 with Quick Reports to print values from an Access database with the field names having months from January to December and data types as number. I have designed a form with `QRDBrep` then inserted `QRDBtext` that displays the amount paid values from the database which is connected with a `TADOQuery` component.

How do I add the field values in the `QRDBtext`? I have tried using a `QRExpr` as follows:

```
SUM(ADOQuery1.January + ADOQuery1.february...)
```

but the results are blank in the preview. Is there a way of adding the `QRDBtext` values using a `QRExpr` or any other way of doing it?

Comment: Which preview are you talking about? There are two: the one you get at design-time, when you right-click the report and choose *Preview* from the context menu, and the one you get when you use the report's `Preview` method at runtime. I'm also not sure why you'd use `SUM` to add horizontally (across a row); it's an aggregate function that adds *rows* (vertically) across an entire result set.

Comment: Ken White I am previewing the report at runtime

Comment: OK. Can you [edit] your question to indicate that there? It makes a difference (design-time preview does not execute expressions, run-time should).